# Count all rows and show a limited number of them in a single json object

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

My query is

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t))) from (
    select count(*) over() as total, id,title
    FROM notifications 
    WHERE  title ilike '%a%'
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 1)t
```

and the output is

```
[
    {
        "title": "Sartaj                                                              ", 
        "id": 3,
        "total":16
    }
]
```

The result includes the total in object, but I want to move it outside the object.

My expected answer is

```
[
    "total":16,
    "data":[
{
        "title": "Sartaj                                                       ", 
        "id": 3
    }]
 ]
```

I also tried

```
with tmp_notifications as (
    SELECT id,title,description,img_url,link,created_on from notifications 
    where title ilike '%universi%'
    ) 
    select row_to_json(t) from (
        select count(*) as data_count,
        (json_agg(json_build_object('description',description,'title',title,'created_on',created_on,
        'link',link,'img_url',img_url,'id',id)) 
         ) as data from tmp_notifications limit 1
        )t
```

but limit is not working here.

Comment: Postgres version?

Comment: PostgreSQL 10.3 (Ubuntu 10.3-1.pgdg14.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4, 64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`json_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) and [`json_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select json_build_object('total', count(*), 'data', json_agg(to_json(t)))
from (
    select id, title
    from notifications 
    where  title ilike '%a%'
    ) t
```

See the full example in [DbFiddle.](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=cd928443877db077867d0825ea159553)

---

You can use a `WITH` statement to count all filtered rows but show the limited number of them, e.g.:

```
with filtered as (
    select id, title
    from notifications 
    where title ilike '%a%'
)

select json_build_object(
    'total', (select count(*) from filtered), 
    'data', json_agg(to_json(t)))
from (
    select id, title
    from filtered
    order by id
    limit 2
    ) t
```

[DbFiddle.](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=9769f68e97534487a470ecb7f2ef442d)

Comment: the main problem is limit is not working here suppose this query gives 100 records then my count is 100 and i want to return only 10 results, this is my problem #klin

Comment: Answer is useful, but one drawback is by using it we are iterating in filtered two times  which is not optimized.

Comment: `count(*)` on CTE scan is really fast, actually unnoticeable. See the [example plan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/b7v7) on a 100000 rows table